# Slow excel worksheet with scatter diagrams

Tags: excel, performance, scatter-plot

I have an excel worksheet with 20 scatter diagrams. All diagrams contain about 30.000 datapoints. I'm aware of the low plotting speed in excel (i'm using 2010). However my problem isn't with the plotting itself. The big problem is that not all the plots fit on one screen so I have to scroll often. When I scroll the system becomes very slow and it seems like the diagrams are all redrawn. You can actually see the plots become blank and then the datapoints appear one by one.

Is there a way to turn off updating or 'freeze' the diagrams once they have been plotted? 
I tried, turing screenupdating off but that doesnt solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Workbook.DisplayDrawingObjects=xlHide
```